# Android change contact picture

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I'm building an app where when a image is clicked the user sees the contacts list and picks one. After clicking on it, it's contact picture should change to the image clicked in the first place.
Here's how i implement it:

```
....
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_CONTACT);
.....
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_CONTACT) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                ????? what should come here???
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is how do i acces and change the contact picture?
Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, get the Uri for the Contacts first raw contact:

```
Uri rawContactUri = null;
Cursor rawContactCursor =  managedQuery(
        RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, 
        new String[] {RawContacts._ID}, 
        RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactData.getLastPathSegment(), 
        null, 
        null);
if(!rawContactCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    rawContactCursor.moveToFirst();
    rawContactUri = RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(""+rawContactCursor.getLong(0)).build();
}
rawContactCursor.close();
```

Then, convert a bitmap to a byte array:

```
Bitmap bit; // <-- put your bitmap here
ByteArrayOutputStream streamy = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bit.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, streamy); 
byte[] photo = streamy.toByteArray();
```

Finally, set the byte array as the raw contact's photo:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
int photoRow = -1; 
String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " == " + 
    ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri) + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=='" + 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'"; 
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        where, 
        null, 
        null); 
int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID); 
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){ 
    photoRow = cursor.getInt(idIdx); 
} 
cursor.close(); 
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 
        ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri)); 
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1); 
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photo); 
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE); 
if(photoRow >= 0){ 
    this.getContentResolver().update(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
            values, 
            ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = " + photoRow, null); 
    } else { 
        this.getContentResolver().insert(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                values); 
    } 
}
```

*EDIT*

Be sure to include these two permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but my app chashes when it executes the first part of the code

Comment: When I change the photo, it is changed and I can see it on the phonebook app. But after some seconds it is reverted automatically (or deleted if there was no previous photo). I suspect it has something to do with the Google account sync. Any ideas on how to fix it?