# unable to update contact photo in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to update the contact photo in android using the below code,

public void setPhoto(String cid, byte[] photo) {

```
int result;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photo);
        result = getContentResolver().update
                (ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, values, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
                        + " = " + cid, null);
    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Number of rows updated " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

I'm getting the result, updated row as 1, but the contact photo is not being updated. Am i missing anything here.

my AndroidManifest.xml file has the following content,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to use RAW_CONTACT_ID to update contact. Please refer this [link](http://android-contact-id-vs-raw-contact-id.blogspot.de/) for more details.
Then you can use the code from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968156/android-change-contact-picture) to update photo